# Angular2 dependent dropdown based on selected value

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Here am trying to append a dependent drop down based on value drop  down (you can see in my HTML code for value drop down).I have wrote a   onchage method to get appear dependent dropdown in html.Here i have   dependent drop down for only three(i.e, Services Performed, Products   Sold, Gross Retail) selected values of my values dropdown. Now am   getting the dependent dropdowns, but when i have change the another   drop down i.e, 2nd or 3rd ...etc dropdown ,then the previous   drop down is getting disappear and latest changed dropdown value is   getting appear.

so, please help me to solve it.

my HTML code is

```
<table class="table table-bordered-light">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="grey_th">
                <td>Step</td>
                <td>Action</td>
                <td>Value</td>
                <td>Number</td>
                <td>Sample Calculation</td>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = 'index'">
                <td [innerHTML]="row.step"></td>
                <td>
                    <select [class.disabled]="i==0" [(ngModel)]="row.operator" name="action" style="width: 100%">
                        <option *ngFor="let actions of actionsStaticData; let i='index'" value="{{actions.id}}" id="actions{{i}}">{{actions.action}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div>
       <!-- here i have wrote onchange method **onValueChange()** and passing i also along with the value -->


    <
 [(ngModel)]="row.operand" style="width: 100%" (change)="onValueChange($event.target.value, i)">
                                            <option *ngFor="let values of valuesStaticData; let i='index'" value="{{values.value}}" id="values{{i}}">{{values.value}}</option>
                                            <option value="-" disabled="disabled">-----</option>
                                            <option *ngFor="let values of scalesData; let i='index'" value="{{values.Id}}" id="values{{i}}">{{values.Name}}</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="ml-15" *ngIf='rowLength == i'>
                                        <select [(ngModel)]="row.operandSubOption" style="width: 100%">
                                            <option *ngFor="let values of servicesList; let i='index'" value="{{values.value}}" id="values{{i}}">{{values.Name}}</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="row.numeral">
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;{{row.result}}{{toFix}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a style="color: #000;" (click)="addRows()" *ngIf='showPlus == true'>
                                <span class="f-plus">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a *ngIf='showPlus == false'>
                                <!-- <span class="del">
                <i class="fa fa-plus disable" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span> -->
                            </a>
                            <a (click)="deleteFieldValue(row, i)" *ngIf='hideDelete==true' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Remove">
                                <span class="f-minus">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
```

my typesript code is

```
 onValueChange(value, i) {
        if (value === 'Services Performed') {
            this.rowLength = i;
            this.servicesList = '';
            this.setupCompMethodService.getServices()
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.servicesList = data['result'];
                    this.rows[i]['operandSubOption'] = this.servicesList[0].Name;
                });
        }
        if (value === 'Products Sold') {
            this.rowLength = i;
            this.servicesList = '';
            this.setupCompMethodService.getInventoryGroupData()
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.servicesList = data['result'];
                    this.rows[i]['operandSubOption'] = this.servicesList[0].Name;
                });``
        }
        if (value === 'Gross Retail') {
            this.rowLength = i;
            this.servicesList = '';
            this.setupCompMethodService.getProductLineDetails()
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.servicesList = data['result'];
                    this.rows[i]['operandSubOption'] = this.servicesList[0].Name;
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please improve your markup, it's terrible to try and read it now ;) Also would be great if you could provide a demo showcasing this issue.

Comment: will you support for screen share..? if you are ready, i will share my screen